# Ignite cluster preloading

Tags: ignite

I have a ignite server cluster. It's a read-through cache. No native persistance. On heap mode is enabled. Want to preload it as I can't afford the initial miss using data streamer.
I have two question-

1. I can see after a restart of cluster JVM, the cache cluster still holding data? is it due to its durable memory in off-heap?
2. Is there any way to do a clean start on JVM restart?
3. While loading data via streamer, I am getting ***IllegalStateException: Duplicate Key*** exception. What could be the reason? there is no indexing done so far and override is false in data streamer.

Comment: 1,2 The cluster without persistence should not hold any data after the restart. Please check that you stop all server nodes. Offheap as well as onheap memory is not durable. Onheap caching is just an additional layer useful in case of multiple reads of the same record[1]  

3. Please show the cluster configuration.


[1] https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/configuring-caches/on-heap-caching#on-heap-caching

Comment: So JVM is bounced or the application is restarted. The main physical server which hosted this app is shared with other apps and is still running.
So in short, JVM is bounced but the main RAM is not.

Comment: You do not need to power cycle actual hardware.

Answer (score 0):

To discard all data, you need to stop all server nodes at the same time while having persistence disabled. Please note that if you still have at least one node in the grid, it will start to rebalance data so some may survive even repeated rolling restart of all nodes.

Comment: Any way to programmatically flushing to make sure the cluster is clean on startup?

Comment: There is currently no way of preventing node from rejoining the old cluster, which is what you are avoiding here.